# M-x menu display like spacemacs

Tags: init-file, themes

For some reason, I am not getting spacemacs. But I need the feature that when I do M-x, it displays the column of menu of commands, which I can select from using direction keys (Up and Down) and confirm by pressing Enter.

Can anyone tell me how to write the init.el to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: I've never used spacemacs, but I assume it's just using `helm` for that functionality, so you'll have to install and configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`helm-config` package provides this functionality to show commands in a mini buffer. All we need to do is to bind the key `M-x` to command `helm-M-x`.

In your init.el file:

```
(require 'helm-config)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
```